# Convert any xpath to css selector in Ruby

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath

I have a Rails application where the user (trained to do so) introduces an xpath for a specific element on an html page.

The users are not trained in CSS selectors so I prefer not to re-train them.

I then need to export the xpath to a css selector so it can be used to attach actions on the element on the client side in a browser-run JS script.

Is there a gem that can do this?

I can see Nokogiri has an [xpath_for](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FCSS%2FParser%3Axpath_for) method that can convert CSS to Xpath but not the reverse.

As an alternative, I can convert the xpath to css at runtime with JS using this [NPM library](https://github.com/jonathanp/xpath-to-css) (I need to port it to browser-compatible JS first) - but I prefer to convert the xpath server-side.